# Google App Script Import CSV to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which i want to import a CSV File stored in my drive.

this is my code:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("file.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TEST'))
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

I get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of undefined". I would like to import my data of the CSV into the "TEST" Tab. How i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that when I saw your script, `sheet` of `sheet.getSheetByName('TEST')` is not declared. If the sheet of sheet name of `TEST` is existing in the Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TEST'))
```

#### To:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST');
```

or

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').activate();
```

#### Reference:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Comment: Yes! Correct thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this question is active anymore, but I'll leave this here for anybody who might benefit from it.

The `.next()` at the end of the third line of code ( `var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("file.csv").next();`) is unnecessary because of [Google Apps Script's new V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime). The code to copy only needs a legitimate txt or csv file.