# Conversion of csv to google sheet splitting data in cells

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used the script which is available on here which helped with converting a csv file to sheets, [Google App Script Import CSV to Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995997/google-app-script-import-csv-to-google-sheets)

The slight problem that is occurring currently is where there is multiple lines under each other in one cell but during the conversion it is splitting the data rather than keeping in the same format / cell

I hope I have explained this is ok

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace all occurances of new line `\n` with " ".  It does not affect the end of line character.

Test sheet

[image]

```
function test() {
  try {
    let file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Tests - Sheet1.csv").next();
    let blob = file.getBlob();
    let string = blob.getDataAsString();
    string = string.replace(/\n/g," ");
    console.log(string);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
9:02:44 AM  Info    before:
9:02:44 AM  Info    Id,Name,"Date
Hello",,TRUE,,,,,,
1,A,1/1/2020,,,,,,,,
2,B,2/2/2020,,,,,,,,
3,C,3/3/2021,,,,,,,,
4,D,4/4/2022,,,,,,,,
5,E,6/6/2022,,,,,,,,
9:02:44 AM  Info    after
9:02:44 AM  Info    Id,Name,"Date Hello",,TRUE,,,,,,
 1,A,1/1/2020,,,,,,,,
 2,B,2/2/2020,,,,,,,,
 3,C,3/3/2021,,,,,,,,
 4,D,4/4/2022,,,,,,,,
 5,E,6/6/2022,,,,,,,,
9:02:44 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: I think quoting is a better option, where each cell is double quoted.